# How to decode image in node js with using bodyparser

Tags: node.js

I have tried decode image file in node js with body parser in and uploaded to server url. but I didn't get success in uplaod and parser image with base64 image.

```
 if (req.method === 'POST') {
    //base64_decode(req.body.profileImg, 'copy.jpeg');
    //console.log(req.body.profileImg);
    var NewImageName =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(req.body.profileImg);
    fs.writeFile('../assets/images/seller/'+NewImageName+'.png', imageBuffer.data, function(err) {

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this code for decoding the base64 image.

```
function decodeBase64Image(dataString) {
  var matches = dataString.match(/^data:([A-Za-z-+\/]+);base64,(.+)$/),
    response = {};

  if (matches.length !== 3) {
    return new Error('Invalid input string');
  }

  response.type = matches[1];
  response.data = new Buffer(matches[2], 'base64');

  return response;
}


app.post('/UploadImages', function (req,res){
    if (req.method === 'POST') {

        var NewImageName =  Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
        var imageBuffer = decodeBase64Image(req.body.profileImg);
        fs.writeFile('../assets/images/seller/'+NewImageName+'.png', imageBuffer.data, function(err) {

        });
        res.json(200, {profileImgName: NewImageName });

    }
});
```

Just get your base64 encoded string in you nodeJs function and you can send it to the function decodeBase64Image i have created above which will decode the Image and then you can upload it.

Thanks